# mount.cifs fails (Error 2, no such file or directory) with credentials file, while -o username,password succeeds

Tags: permissions, rhel, mount, cifs

Long time, first time. I'm running RHEL 7.2 (Maipo), and unable to mount a NAS using credentials stored in a file. The directory mounts successfully if I pass username and password directly in the command line, but I'd like to use a credentials file instead for security reasons

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=myname,password=mypassword //mydomain/share/Users/me /mnt/mydir
# Success
$ printf "username=myname\npassword=mypassword\n" >> mycreds
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=mycreds //mydomain/share/Users/me /mnt/mydir
# error 2 (No such file or directory) opening credential file mycreds
```

The password only contains alphanumeric characters, so it's not an issue with special characters.

Permissions on the credentials file are currently set as follows. I started out as the file owner, but that didn't work either.

```
$ ls -l mycreds
# -rwSr-xr-x. 1 root root 40 Mar 19 18:23 mycreds
```

`mount.cifs --version` returns `mount.cifs version: 6.2`

I haven't added any lines to /etc/fstab while testing `mount`. I'd like to verify it works from command line first.

Let me know if more information would help!

Comment: Remove _group_ and _other_ permissions from the credentials file. Otherwise your security is (at best) no better than providing a username and password on the `mount` command line. Use `chmod u=rw,go= mycreds`

Comment: I have always understood that the credentials file required a tuple of { _username_, _password_, _domain_ }, where _domain_ is your workgroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me figure it out - I was in the directory containing my credentials while running the command, but I needed to provide the absolute path. I'm not sure whether it has to do with the fact that my home directory is in /mnt, but regardless, the following approach succeeds:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/mnt/path/to/mycreds //mydomain/share/Users/me /mnt/mydir
# Success
```